# class not seeing its properties

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

my class

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Task(models.Model):
    id: models.UUIDField(unique=True, auto_created=True)
    content: models.CharField(default="")
    deadline: models.IntegerField(default=None)
    creationDate: models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    author: models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.id) + str(self.content)
```

my error:

> File "/Users/ironside/Documents/Python/PythonDjango-Project/api/models.py", line 13, in **str**

> return str(self.id) + str(self.content)

> AttributeError: 'Task' object has no attribute 'content'

I tested, and all other properties give the same error ('content' changes to property name).

It's as if it only sees id as valid property.

I'd like to be able to print the id + content or any other property

Edit:

Updated model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    id: str = models.UUIDField(
        unique=True,
        auto_created=True,
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    content: str = models.CharField(
        default="",
        max_length=255,
    )
    deadline: int = models.IntegerField(
        default=None,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    creationDate: models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    author: models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.id) + str(self.content)
```

new error

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: table api_task has no column named content

when doing `print(Task.objects.all())`

Answer (score 1):

Actually your model definition is not django orm way.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Task(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, auto_created=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    deadline = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    creationDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.id) + ' ' + self.content
```

Comment: I added your changes and now I'm getting:

Comment: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: table api_task has no column named content`

Comment: did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you're using Annotated assignment instead of just regular assignment?

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#index-15

if you're using annotated for some specific reason you also need to pass in the types as well as assign.

something like this.

```
content: type = models.CharField(default="")
```

Comment: that helped partially. Now I'm getting `django.db.utils.OperationalError: table api_task has no column named content`

Comment: @AlexIronside At this point I would delete all migration tables or if this model if siloed enough just the migrations referencing this table. Then re-run migrations/migrate.